# Spawn new program in Supervisord usering XML-RCP?

Tags: xml-rpc, supervisord

Is it possible to spawn new program in [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) via XML-RCP?

I'm using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to manage my [Apache Qpid](http://qpid.apache.org/) broker and my python workers. I would like to be able to spawn more workers when the number of messages in the queue exceeds a certain limit.

So far I have only managed to start and stop already running processes. But I would like to specify a general program in the supervisord.conf and start them on the fly.

Example program:

```
[program:qpid_worker]
command=python path/to/worker.py
autorestart=true
process_name=worker
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/worker.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=50MB
stdout_logfile_backups=10
loglevel=warn
```

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not a feature supported by supervisord. It has no facility to create an arbitrary number of processes based on a template.

You'll have to pre-define your workers and start and stop those as needed.

Comment: Ok, then I will just define some extra workers and set the autostart=false and start them when needed. Thanks for the answer!